# Python Class Call Method Self Argument - Why self?

Tags: python, class, methods, self

I'm still quite new at python, and I've looked in a book I got and searched here and on the web.
But I'm not getting an answer that is down to the level I apparently can grasp atm.

I got 2 different class's.

```
main.py

import listManipulator as lm

lc = lm.listManipulator()

li = [some list]
li2 = [some other list]

li = lm.listManipulator.cleanupList(li) # This call method does not requires the method to have the self argument
li2 = lc.cleanupList(li2) # This call method requires the method to have the self argument
```

So I'm trying to call my cleanup method, and I'm getting confused by this self argument, yet again. I'ved figured out there are 2 ways calling the method as shown above.

```
listManipulator.py
class listManipulator:

        def cleanupList(self, list):
              *do stuff*
              return list
```

As you can tell from the comments in the code, in one of the calls, I NEED the ***target method*** to have the ***self*** argument, but I don't in the other. Can anyone give me a down to earth explanation of why the frack this is?

Comment: Why do you think that one does not require the self argument and the other does?

Comment: If you call a method on an instance of a class, that instance is automatically provided as the first parameter to the call (traditionally called `self`).  If you call a method on the class itself, no instance is provided (indeed, there is no instance that even could be provided in that case).

Comment: @mkrieger1 what I've come up with so fare is that `_lm.listManipulater.cleanup..._` "provides" the instance of the class, and fore some reason, that negates the need for the _self_ argument.
And the `_lc.cleanup..._` points to an already instantiated instance of the class, which for some reason makes it need the _self_ argument.

@jasonharper I kind of get what your saying, but I'm still quite confused.. :/ Calling on the class it self is where I need the _self_ argument?

Comment: TL;DR: If you're calling the function *on the class*, not on an instance, then there is no `self` which gets automatically passed (because there's no instance which _could_ get passed). If you're calling the method on an instance, then it *does* get a `self` argument passed implicitly. For more info, read the two duplicates linked above.

Comment: @deceze Am I getting this right, using __lm.listManipulater.cleanup....__ there is no instantiated instance and therefor no instance "__self__" there to get passed, therefor the method has no need for the argument?

Comment: “No need” is a weird way of putting it. You decide whether the method has “a need” for `self` when writing it. That also determines how you want to call the method later. The error here is that you’re calling it two different inconsistent ways.

Comment: @deceze okay, it's not that I want to call it in different ways, it's more a case of trying to get a grasp on the differences and when to use which. Not knowing what is "best practices". I'm kind of thinking it should be a static method, since the class won't take any attributes.

Comment: Yes, instance methods which accept a `self` are the standard case, as that's what you want 95% of the time. If you have special cases like static methods or class methods, that's where you'd use the `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` decorators explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Python Classes can have different types of functions, what you are describing are *class* and *static* methods.

A class method requieres a class instance with a self variable:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
 
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

# Create an instance of MyClass
obj = MyClass(10)
 
# Call the get_value method on the instance
print(obj.get_value())  # Output: 10
```

But theres also a static method that does not require the class instance and you create it by decorading it with a **@staticmethod** decorator:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @staticmethod
    def get_max_value(x, y):
        return max(x, y)

# Create an instance of MyClass
obj = MyClass(10)

print(MyClass.get_max_value(20, 30)) # Output: 30

print(obj.get_max_value(20, 30)) # Output: 30
```